# Generate alert message if condition occurs otherwise show the app

Tags: bootstrap-4, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

**Objective**: I would like to pop an Alert component if a condition occurs (i.e no data from URL pathname)
otherwise render the app

**What I've tried so far**

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Alert([...], id='alert', is_open=False),
    dbc.Container([rows & columns (all visuals are here)], id='page1')
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('alert', 'is_open'),
     Output('store-component', 'data'),
     Output('page1', 'children')],
    Input('url', 'pathname')
)
def extract_path_from_url(pathname):
    if pathname name contains ... :
       store the dataset in the Store component and **DONT SHOW THE ALERT BUTTON**
    else:
       **SHOW THE ALERT BUTTON** and that's it

    ... other callbacks generating the visuals based on the store-component ...
```

**This didn't work, is there a proper way to achieve this ?**

**EDIT:**
Latest try:

this is my updated callback and layout. So far it works fine when the condition is True , the Alert component doesn't display and everything displays fine. The problem is when the condition is false, the Alert message  shows successfully but the we can see the graphs being empty. I want to hide them or not render them at all...

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Alert([...], id='alert', is_open=False),
    dbc.Container([rows & columns (all visuals are here)], id='container')
])


@app.callback(
    [Output('alert', 'is_open'),
     Output('store-component', 'data'),
     Output('container', 'style')],
    Input('url', 'pathname')
)
def extract_path_from_url(pathname):
    if pathname name contains ... :
       return dash.no_update, data, dash.no_update
    else:
       return True, dash.no_update, {'display': 'none'}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## URL-conditional display of `dbc` "Warning" alert in Python Plotly-Dash app

```py
from dash import Dash, Input, Output
from dash import dcc, html

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

# Sample layout
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        dbc.Alert(
            [
                html.H3("Warning!"),
                html.Hr(),
                html.P("No data found for this URL."),
            ],
            id="alert",
            is_open=False,
            color="warning",
        ),
        dbc.Container(
            [
                # Mock "rows & columns (all visuals are here)"
                html.H1("Main Content"),
                html.Div(
                    "This is the main content that"
                    " will be hidden or shown based on the URL."
                ),
                dcc.Graph(
                    id="example-graph",
                    figure={
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "x": [1, 2, 3],
                                "y": [4, 1, 2],
                                "type": "bar",
                                "name": "Sample Data",
                            },
                        ],
                        "layout": {"title": "Sample Data Visualization"},
                    },
                ),
            ],
            id="container",
        ),
    ],
    style={"margin": "10%"},
)


@app.callback(
    [Output("alert", "is_open"), Output("container", "style")],
    Input("url", "pathname"),
)
def extract_path_from_url(pathname):

    # For demonstration, if pathname contains "nodata", assume no data is found
    if "nodata" in pathname:
        # Show the alert and hide the main content
        return True, {"display": "none"}
    else:
        # Hide the alert and show the main content
        return False, {"display": "block"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

produces:

[image: Demo dash app video screenshot recording showing URL-conditional warning alert display]

Comment: i'd rather use the dbc component alert to show a message. no need for a pop up. i tried adding the style with display == to none but for some reason again , it doesnt work will post what it shows

Comment: @RogerSteinberg Rather late, but, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create  it . Just simply writing the condition  only eg (highest price Crossing
cloing price).aftet writing this you get perfect time of alert when high price going above closing price in single candle .